# Use Rows.Find to Search DataTable for String Value

Tags: c#, datatable, find, datarow

I have a bit of code that I'm stuck on.  I am trying to search the ReasonCodeTable for some values in the DataRow from R64CodeTable so that I can update it.

`Find(_rcdr["Reason Code"])` Works fine, but `Find("R64")` gives me an error of `Input string was not in correct format`

I tried `Find($"R64")` and `Find(@"R64")`, and I even tried `string testme = "R64"` with `Find(testme)`.  None of it works, I continue to get the same error.  "R64" is the actual string/test value I want to look for in the Column values.

```
foreach (DataRow _rcdr in ReasonCodeTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow _dr in R64CodeTable.Rows)
    {
        if ( (R64CodeTable.Rows.Find(_rcdr["Reason Code"]) != null) && (R64CodeTable.Rows.Find("R64") != null) )
        {
            _rcdr["Desciption"] = _dr["description"];
            _rcdr["Who Edited"] = _dr["editwho"];
            _rcdr["Last Edit (UTC)"] = _dr["editdate"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the DataTable's `PrimaryKey`? If you have a single Column as Key, why are you trying to find two values with `&&`. A Column cannot have two values at the same time. -- If you have two Columns as Keys, you can write, e.g., `var row = ReasonCodeTable.Rows.Find(new object[] { _rcdr["Reason Code"], "R64" }); if (row != null) {...}` -- Of course you don't need that nested loop.

Comment: @Jimi PrimaryKey column for R64CodeTable is "ID".   I'm not looking for the the PrimaryKey thought.  My understanding is that Find will look at all the columns, and with the != null, it will give me a true/false if it exists anywhere in any of the columns of that particular row.  It works for `_rcdr["Reason Code"]` which is a reference to another table, but not the string "R64".

Comment: The `Find()` methods only act on Columns that are part of the PrimaryKey object of a DataTable. If you don't want to set a PrimaryKey (because there's isn't one in the original source of data, maybe), then use the `RowFilter` property, where you can specify the names of the Columns you're querying.

Comment: Ok, that kind of makes sense then.  The PrimaryKey is Int32, so the error makes sense.  Doesn't make sense that the first part wasn't throwing an error though.  I'll give RowFilter a try.

Comment: Note that using a filter is a much slower process than querying on indexes (as it has always been). Also note that a `PrimaryKey` can be set temporarily, then dismissed (set to `null`) after use, or reset to its former value. Much depends on the role of this DataTable and the actual use-case. --  A DataTable can also be easily cloned, in case operations on the original object may cause any kind of disruption (which may include unexpectedly moving the `Current` Row)